# How do I test my NativeScript application on the device and am I in Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, emulation, nativescript, development-environment

I'm using a translator because I speak Spanish. I hope they understand me. I'm starting in Nativescript and I have a test application running on an Android emulator, so I want to test that application on my ios device. I have read that to run the command tns run ios it is necessary to do it in mac but I have Windows Any way to do it? , I have also read about Telerik but I still do not know what it is about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in windows is imposible to test IOS, you need to do it on a MAC OS because you need XCode to compile to IOS, even in MAC you need an IOS developer account because of the profiles.

Best regards!